# C# Better way of looping through list and adding values to a new list object

Tags: c#

I was wondering if anyone could show me a nicer way of writing the code below.
Bascially I am looping through a customerRecords lists and calculating the distance between points and then creating a new object CustomerDistanceRecord and adding it to a CustomerDistanceRecord list and then return the list. Thanks

```
    public List<CustomerDistanceRecord> Distance(List<CustomerRecords> customerRecords)
    {
        var customerList = new List<CustomerDistanceRecord>();
        foreach(var customer in customerRecords)
        {
            var calcaulatedDistance = CalculateDistance(customer);
            var customerDistanceRecord = new CustomerDistanceRecord()
            {
                UserId = customer.UserId,
                Name = customer.Name,
                DistanceFromOfficeLocation = calcaulatedDistance
            };
            customerList.Add(customerDistanceRecord);
        }
        return customerList;
    }

        private double CalculateDistance(CustomerRecords customer)
        {
            double theta = customer.Longitude - OfficeLocation.Longitude;
            double dist = Math.Sin(deg2rad(customer.Latitude)) * Math.Sin(deg2rad(OfficeLocation.Latitude)) 
                + Math.Cos(deg2rad(customer.Latitude)) * Math.Cos(deg2rad(OfficeLocation.Latitude)) * Math.Cos(deg2rad(theta));
            dist = Math.Acos(dist);
            dist = rad2deg(dist);
            dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
            dist *= 1.609344;
            return dist;
        }
```

Comment: This might be better asked on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) since it's not requesting help to resolve a problem.

Comment: Thanks i was not aware of code review

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this LINQ-expression:

```
var customerList = customerRecords.Select(g => new CustomerDistanceRecord
        {
            UserId = g.UserId,
            Name = g.Name,
            DistanceFromOfficeLocation = CalculateDistance(g)
        }).ToList();
```